# virtual and constexpr before up to C++17

Tags: c++, virtual, constexpr-function

I'm confused about what I read about mixing `virtual` and `constexpr` for member functions.
According to:

- [constexpr and virtual](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47278502/constexpr-and-virtual)
- [Can virtual functions be constexpr?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34828161/can-virtual-functions-be-constexpr)
- [constexpr in cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constexpr)

up to C++17 included, it should not be possible to mix `constexpr` and `virtual` (standard is quoted in above links)

Yet I designed this straightfoward example:

```cpp
#include <cstddef>

struct SizedObject {
    virtual size_t GetSize() const = 0;
};

struct DynSizedObject : public SizedObject {
    size_t s;
    size_t GetSize() const override final { return s; }
};

struct StatSizedObject : public SizedObject {
    const size_t s;
    constexpr size_t GetSize() const override final { return s; }
    constexpr explicit StatSizedObject(const size_t i) : s(i) {}
};

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    constexpr StatSizedObject SS(42);
    DynSizedObject DS;
    DS.s = argc + 2;
    SizedObject const * p;
    if (argc > 3) {
        p = &SS;
    } else {
        p = &DS;
    }

    return p->GetSize();
}
```

I'm designing a hierarchy of objects with a *size* property that can be retrieved through the `GetSize` member function, which I make `virtual`. Now one of the concrete class can be instantiated with a compile-time size, and I make its `GetSize` override `constexpr`. Then my toy example trick the compiler in not knowing, at compile-time, which object will call `GetSize`. In the [Live](https://godbolt.org/z/68bjd7cv1) I'm surprised to see that gcc accept the code. clang reject it, seemingly consistant with the standard, while msvc do as clang but also claim that the `constexpr` version *cannot result in a constant expression*, which seems incorrect to me.

Thus my understanding would be that all compiler should behave like clang (but don't): is it correct? In this case, is it a gcc "bug" that it is accepting this construct? subsidiary question: why does msvc issue the *cannot result in a constant expression* error?

Beyond an academic interest, my purpose is to know if I may use some compile-time optimisation technics in relation with dynamic polymorphism (up to C++17, I know that, from C++20, [some designs](https://www.cppstories.com/2021/constexpr-virtual/) are possible).

Comment: Your example is not using `constexpr` at all, try `constexpr StatSizedObject SS(42);`

Comment: @Oersted: "*subsidiary question: why does msvc issue the cannot result in a constant expression error?*" Because that's the consequence of doing a thing that you can't do with `constexpr`. If you do something with a type that prevents its use in a `constexpr` context, then it can't be used in that context.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### C++17

In C++17, the above code would be ill-formed. What you have discovered is a compiler bug in GCC. The standard is very clear on this:

> The definition of a constexpr function shall satisfy the following requirements:
>
> - it shall not be [virtual](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/class.virtual);
> - [...]

- [[dcl.constexpr] p3](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/dcl.constexpr#3)

> If a virtual member function `vf` is declared in a class `Base` and in a class `Derived`, derived directly or indirectly from `Base`, a member function `vf` with the same name, parameter-type-list, cv-qualification, and ref-qualifier (or absence of same) as `Base​::​vf` is declared, then `Derived​::​vf` is also virtual (whether or not it is so declared) and it overrides<sup>[111](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/class.virtual#footnote-111)</sup> `Base​::​vf`.

- [[class.virtual] p2](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/class.virtual#2)

From these two sections we can conclude that `constexpr virtual` functions are disallowed, and any function that overrides a `virtual` function also cannot be `constexpr`, because it is implicitly `virtual`.

#### GCC Diagnostics

Interestingly enough, we get no diagnostics for `GetSize` being `virtual constexpr`, even though it is a virtual function according to the standard.

```cpp
// implicitly virtual because of it overrides SizedObject::GetSize
constexpr size_t GetSize() const override final { return s; }
```

If we mark the function `virtual` redundantly, we do get diagnostics:

```cpp
constexpr virtual size_t GetSize() const override final { return s; }
```

> ```cpp
> <source>:14:15: warning: member 'GetSize' can be declared both 'virtual' and > 'constexpr' only in '-std=c++20' or '-std=gnu++20' [-Wc++20-extensions]
>    14 |     constexpr virtual size_t GetSize() const override final { return s; }
>       |     ~~~~~~~~~ ^~~~~~~
> ```

#### MSVC Diagnostics

As for:

> subsidiary question: why does msvc issue the cannot result in a constant expression error?

Admittedly, this is not a very intuitive error message. It's simply what MSVC outputs for all cases where a function cannot be `constexpr` because of its signature. You get the same message when making the return type of a `constexpr` function `std::vector<int>`.

In general, `constexpr` means that at least for some arguments, a function has to be able to result in a constant expression. If the function signature makes that impossible, then specifying `constexpr` is wrong.

### C++20

C++20 lifted these restrictions on `constexpr virtual` functions, so the above code would be well-formed.